# Warn against improper usage of operator&

Tags: c++, mysql, reference

To be paranoid and overprotective, I'm wondering if there's a way to issue a compiler warning against usage of this pattern which causes a segfault due to SQLString being freed and the resultant const std::string& referencing something that was already freed.

```
const std::string& str(rs->getString("field1"));
int d = rs->getInt("field2");

// access to str causes a segfault
```

rs->getString is of type SQLString from https://github.com/anhstudios/mysql-connector-cpp/blob/master/cppconn/sqlstring.h and by initializing str above, the

```
operator const std::string &() const
```

is being called

Comment: Where is `rs` freed in your example? And does `getString` (where is that function anyway?) really return by reference? Anyway, there's no way. Also, why use `SQLString` instead of `std::string`, if neccessary a derived class only adding non-virtual functions?

Comment: Is there some reason you can't just take a copy?

Comment: In C++11, this could be avoided by `SQLString` declaring the conversion operator as `operator const std::string &() &` so that it cannot be called for temporaries. Optionally, something would also be added for rvalues. Unfortunately, this library does not make use of it, and based on how it's written, I don't see how a compiler could legitimately warn for your code without also a huge number of false positives (warning where the compiler shouldn't warn). BTW, there's no use of the `&` operator in your code. There is a `&` symbol, but in that context it's not an operator.

Comment: @shuttle87 I want to but I can't guarantee other users won't, it seems they are used to an old version of the library where getString() would return std::string..

Comment: @hvd thank you for your thoughtful response, I will try that out

Comment: @hvd: I tried changing to operator const std::string &() & but now I can't even do const std::string str = rs->getString("field1") which should be allowed

Comment: @stgtscc I did suggest that a separate approach for rvalues might be useful to add as well. But it needs to not return a reference. Perhaps `operator string () &&`? (And make sure to move, not copy, here.)